# what does it mean if an element is "blocking"?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm looking over the documentation for hammer.js v2, it says that the pinch and rotate triggers are disabled by default because they make an element "blocking".

http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

What does that mean?

I would guess that it's blocking page scrolling when scrolling over that element?

Answer (score 0):

*Blocking* refers to the fact that while that recognizer is running, no other UI or Javascript code can run. Well-behaved applications try to avoid getting into slow loops in Javascript, because they make the page non-responsive. This is why most things that involves delays or waiting for something (such as the response to an AJAX request) use asynchronous callbacks rather than synchronous return values.

It sounds like the code of these recognizers is not written in an asynchronous manner. This may be necessary because the gestures would mistakenly be recognized as dragging if the recognizers allowed other code to run at the same time.

Comment: Blocking in the docs means the scroll-lock you will get while touching an element. Like when you reach at a Google Maps element on a page on your smartphone, and can't scroll away from it.

It has nothing to do with async/sync or UI updates.

Comment: That isn't just one of the effects of blocking other UI functions?